# If the solution to my question is on a comment, should I mark it the answer as accepted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, accepted-answer

I posted a question and someone answered. Then, another user commented on that answer (with a different solution) and I ended up using this second solution to solve my problem.

Should I mark that answer as accepted (even though I didn't use (or tested) the solution given in there)? And how do I give credit to the user who commented and solved my problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best thing to do is to ask that second responder -- in a comment on that first answer, using @TheirUserName to call them out -- to put their comment into an answer, so you can upvote and accept it. Often people will do this if you ask.

As [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140890/martijn-pieters) points out, if they don't do it themselves after a reasonable period of time has passed, you can create the answer yourself, marking it as community wiki (so you cannot be accused of reputation pilfering), then upvote and accept it.

Comment: And if they don't, after some time create the answer as a community wiki (so's you cannot be accused of reputation pilfering) so's it can be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If the answer has been given in a comment for an answer, and the user who wrote the comment is not the same who wrote the answer, then you should not accept the answer to accept the comment.

You should rather write a comment asking to who wrote the comment to write it as answer, as that is the solution, and you mean to accept her/his answer.
If that user is not going to write that as answer, after some days you could write your own answer using the text of that comment, and giving attribution to who wrote that comment. You could also make your answer a Community Wiki, and that is generally suggested.